# Returning a row even when it shouldn't find one in the table

Tags: mysql, resultset

Here is my SQL

```
SELECT items.name, items.id, items.price,
COUNT(cart_items.itemId) AS quantity
FROM `cart_items`
LEFT JOIN `items`
ON cart_items.itemId = items.id
WHERE cart_items.cartId = '2'
```

There are no rows in the table `cart_items` with the `cartId` of 2. Yet, the resultset still shows one empty row. Why? What's wrong with my query?

(If I set `cart_items.cartId ='1'` (there are rows in the table with `cartId` of 1) then everything returns fine.

Excuse me, I'm quite new to this kind of MySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you use COUNT() (an aggregating function). You should move counting items to a subquery.